# Java RegExp to get variable image name with its extension from javascript

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to get the image name from the following javascript.

```
var g_prefetch ={'Im': {url:'\/az\/hprichbg\/rb\/WhiteTippedRose_ROW10477559674_1366x768.jpg', hash:'674'}
```

Problem:

*The name of the image is variable. That is, in the above example code the image changes regularly.*

Output I want:

```
WhiteTippedRose_ROW10477559674_1366x768.jpg
```

and i tried the following regExp :

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\{\'Im\'\: \{url\:\'\\\/az\\\/hprichbg\\\/rb\\\/(.*?)\.jpg\'\, hash\:\'674\'\}");
                    //System.out.println(p);
                    Matcher m=p.matcher(out);
                        if(m.find())                            {
                            System.out.println(m.group());

                            }
```

I don't know too much RegExp so please help me and let me understand the approach.
 Thank You

Comment: ...or you could use a json parser...

Comment: @radai could you please guide me for json parser in java - thanks for your quick reply

Comment: @radai: that's what I thought first, but this is not JSON.

Comment: @JBNizet - are you certain? maybe the OP just ommitted a closing bracket? @ BOSS - assumming this is indeed json, have a look at this question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13796045/java-json-library-that-supports-dom-style-access

Comment: JSON uses double quoutes, and not simple quotes.

Comment: A simple regexp such as [^\/]*.jpg should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use the following regex, it should be fast enough:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[^/]+\\.jpg");
Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
if (m.find()) {
  String match = m.group();
  System.out.println(match);
}
```

This will match the a full sequence of characters ending with *.jpg* not including */*.

I think that the correct approach will be to check the correct legality of a file name.

Here is a list of not legal characters for Windows: `"\\/:*?\"<>|"`
for Mac `/:`
Linux/Unix `/`;

Here is more complex example assuming format will change , it is mostly designed for legal Window file name:

```
String s = "{'Im': {url:'\\/az\\/hprichbg\\/rb\\/?*<>WhiteTippedRose_ROW10477559674_1366x768.jpg', hash:'674'}";

Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[^\\/:*?\"<>|]+\\.jpg");
Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
if (m.find()) {
  String match = m.group();
  System.out.println(match);
}
```

This will still print
`WhiteTippedRose_ROW10477559674_1366x768.jpg`

Here you may find a [demo](http://ideone.com/wrpF3v)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the image is always placed after a `/` and does not contain any `/`, you can use the following:

```
String s = "{'Im': {url:'\\/az\\/hprichbg\\/rb\\/WhiteTippedRose_ROW10477559674_1366x768.jpg', hash:'674'}";
s = s.replaceAll(".*?([^/]*?\\.jpg).*", "$1");
System.out.println("s = " + s);
```

outputs:

> s = WhiteTippedRose_ROW10477559674_1366x768.jpg

In substance:

```
.*?             skip the beginning of the string until the next pattern is found
([^/]*?\\.jpg)  a group like "xxx.jpg" where xxx does not contain any "/"
.*              rest of the string
$1              returns the content of the group
```

Answer (score 0):

If the String is always of this form, I would simply do:

```
int startIndex = s.indexOf("rb\\/") + 4;
int endIndex = s.indexOf('\'', startIndex);
String image = s.substring(startIndex, endIndex);
```