# Is there a way to retrieve a JSON path based on location in input text

Tags: java, json

In a case where I have a JSON input text editor and JSON Parser (eg: Jackson), how do I link between the location of where my cursor is to what path in the JSON I'm currently looking for? Something similar to how when editing a JSON file in VSCode, it is able to detect what your cursor is at in the outline. For example, with JSON:

```
{  
    "employee": {  
        "name":       "sonoo",   
        "salary":      56000,   
        "married":    true  
    }  
}
```

How do I retrieve what Line 3: Character 10 (the n in name) is pointing to in the JSON Object? Looking for libraries or implementations that may help.

Comment: What are you trying to implement? A web app or a desktop application?

Comment: May be useful: There is a nice [collection of JSON-Libraries on GitHub](https://github.com/burningtree/awesome-json)

Comment: @SimonMartinelli i'm planning to make a desktop application. a JavaFX (probably) text editor that shows the JSON path of where the cursor is at while editing (eg: if its at `employee->name` it'll show `employee.name` as a path)

Comment: I am not sure why a discinction between Desktop or web app makes sense here.

Comment: If you use a JSON parser in generic mode (where the JSON document would be parsed into generic Java Map and List types there is no such metainformation available. So you would have to use a parser supporting something like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13796045/java-json-library-that-supports-dom-style-access